# Inequality related to the Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, inequality, prime-numbers

Let $\psi(x)$ be the Chebyshev function. How can I prove the following theorem?

The quotient $\frac{\psi(x)}{x}$ takes its maximum value at $x=113$ and for $x>0$ \begin{equation}
\psi(x)<1.03883x.
\end{equation}

I saw this result in J Barkley Rosser y Lowell Schoenfeld. “Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers”. Illinois Journal of Mathematics 6.1 (1962), págs. 64-94.
That is theorem 12,vbut there is no proof. Where can i see the proof?

Answer (score 0):

A trail of clues leading to the desired proof start on page 80 of that paper (where "Theorem 12" is mentioned). Note in particular that the $b=29$ line of Table 1 (page 90) proves Theorem 12 for $x\ge e^{29}$ and thus for $x>4\times10^{12}$. These days it wouldn't be hard to verify Theorem 12 for $x\le4\times10^{12}$ by brute force or something slightly better.